# RPi Zero WiFi and USB OTG

Tags: gpio, wifi, pi-zero

I'm quite new to this kind of things, but I've jumped out with an idea of a device to give the ability to mount network shares as they where normal pendrives (like for TVs and other old devices).

I started gathering information about it and thought a RPi Zero was a good starting point, since it has USB-OTG.

OS side there should be no problems: according to these sources I can easily mount the network share on the Pi and so on the USB (OTG device mode).

1. [RPi to emulate a USB mass storage device? - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33545/rpi-to-emulate-a-usb-mass-storage-device)
2. [How to share a folder as an USB mass storage device (from a raspberry pi) - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/425667/how-to-share-a-folder-as-an-usb-mass-storage-device-from-a-raspberry-pi)

And now it comes the difficult part.

From what I've read (but I might be wrong) USB-OTG has two operation modes: *host*, the classic one, and *device*, that allows it to be seen as an external device. I've also read that only A models (I'm sure of that about RPi Zero) support OTG, while others don't since they use USB HUBs that put the port only in host mode.

So, the question is: how do I get both network (WiFi) and USB-OTG functionality working on the RPi Zero?

Google shows a couple of suggestions (sorry, can't post more links):

1. *WiFi through ESP8266 for Raspberry Pi Zero - Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange* but is seems to be very slow and unstable (~ 1 Mbps, definitely to slow to stream a whatever compressed video from a NAS, in case of a TV).
2. *RPi WiFi - Fast RPi WiFi without USB* that looks very promising even if quite difficult to follow.
3. *SHABPi WiFi & SD Card Slot for Pi Zero* based on 3 that, as suggested in the *RPi forums* (/forums/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=137710), can get up to 40 Mbps, pretty cool! But where can I get it?
4. *RPi Zero IoT HAT*, but I cannot find any info about the speed despite image available in the Github page and I'm quite skeptical they can get 72 Mbps out of a GPIO connection.

Thank you for any help and/or clarification you can give me, I hope one day I'll be able to answer any of the questions asked here!

Comment: *"I'm quite skeptical they can get 72 Mbps out of a GPIO connection"* -> I am too, but the same logic applies to the SHABPi board, which uses SPI, and to be fair that's [documented in theory as working up to 125 MHz](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/spi/README.md#hardware).  WRT to the SHABPi I think you have to build it yourself: https://hackaday.io/project/10097-shabpi-wifi-sd-card-slot-for-pi-zero

Comment: Worth a look: https://oshlab.com/esp8266-raspberry-pi-gpio-wifi/ ...I found a link to that in [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53898/5538).  "GPIO0/ID_SC" is physical pin 27; here's a chart of [the various alt functions](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/53898/5538).  Probably much easier than the SHABPi; there's a link to similar hackaday page on the oshlab one: [RPi WiFi](https://hackaday.io/project/8678-rpi-wifi).

Comment: Thank you very much @goldilocks for your hints, I'm sure they will help not only me, but also many other people since this seems to be a quite spread topic (especially with RPi Zero).

Comment: I know this is quite old, but this may be related: https://superuser.com/questions/215466/make-nas-appear-as-a-usb-drive/1613829#1613829 - the newer Raspberry Pi SBCs may have USB OTG and Wi-Fi, especially the Pi Zero W. See other hardware referenced in this answer.